# Applying kirchoffs law in a simple circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, wire, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: e circuit]

Can we apply Kirchhoff's volatge law in this simple circuit and say V1=-r1I1 and V2=r2I2 or is there an other connection between voltages and currents?

Comment: It all depends on what those circles represent.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the answer sir!They are voltage sources.

Comment: @user287001 Woah dude you are scaring me please stop it

Comment: I can well remove the comment but that doesn't create any solutions. Removed.

Comment: Homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 2):

Kirchhoff's Laws are not needed here. If you have an ideal voltage source, and the source value is given (whether a literal value or a function of other circuit values) then you can state the voltage across that source by inspection.

Comment: So could we say V1=-I1r1?

Comment: The polarity of V1 is **defined** with a direction that is opposite of the **defined** polarity of the source on the left.

Comment: How could you relate V1 to V2 then?

Comment: There is no relationship between the values of V1 and V2 as they are drawn in this diagram. They are independent voltages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Kirchoff’s voltage law is a law and can always be applied around a loop in a circuit. If you’ve defined your polarities correctly KVL will give you a correct answer

Comment: And is the correct answer the one i suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from their drawing, OP is studying [two-port networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network).

[image]

That said, OP's task may be to find impendence, admittance, or hybrid parameters, and `r_1, r_2` are not given values, but the values to be calculated. If so, and if the sources are independent, Ohm's law is sufficient for solving this simple problem:
$$
z_{11} = {-V_1 \over I_1}\\
z_{22} = {V_2 \over I_2}\\
z_{12} = z_{21} = 0\\
(r_1=z_{11}; r_2=z_{22})
$$